# How do I delete files greater than a certain date on linux

Tags: linux, command-line, archiving

Occasionally I extract an an archive into the wrong folder and would like to move or delete the newly extracted files.

What is the easiest way to do this via the command line? Can I somehow search for all files that are newer than the extraction time and pipe that into rm?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, `tar` modifies the mtime and ctime of the extracted files to match the dates in the archive, so this first method won't work unless the `-m` flag was used during extraction. The last method is optimal, but may result in deleting files you want if filenames collide.

`find` supports a `-newer` *`file`* flag, specifying it should find files newer than *file*. `touch` has a -t argument to modify the access/modify time on a file. So to fix an oops that occurred around 7:25:30 PM:

```
$ tar xzf whoops.tar.gz
$ touch -t 200909261925.30 whoops-timestamp
$ find . -newer whoops-timestamp
```

And if you're confident that displayed the correct files:

```
$ find . -newer whoops-timestamp -print0 | xargs -0 rm -v
```

An alternative is to delete all the files listed in the archive you just extracted:

```
$ tar tfz whoops.tar.gz | xargs rm -v
```

Comment: (+1) The last option is the best. It's safer and nicer than what the OP had in mind.

Comment: question: wouldn't tar set the modified time to that of the original files?  Wouldn't find use that modified time (vs change time?) during it's comparison?

Comment: Thanks! I used the last way of doing it. The archive was actually a zip so I did zipinfo -1 blah.zip | xargs rm -v

Comment: @ericslaw Yup, that does seem to be the case. `tar` will preserve the dates from the archives unless you use the `-m` flag. So, the first method won't work as a general rule.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative with find:

```
$ find "/path/to_clean/" -type f -mtime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

where the +30 is the number of days you wish to keep.