# How to delete files in linux older than 1 year?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete files greater than a certain date on linux](https://superuser.com/questions/47356/how-do-i-delete-files-greater-than-a-certain-date-on-linux)

How to delete all files in current directory and it`s sub directories older than one year?

Comment: Do `man find`. Boom.

Comment: Note to closers: that other question is actually confusingly different, its answers aren't completely straightforward to transpose.

Answer (score 15):

```
find /the/dir/to/start/in -type f -mtime +365 -ls -exec rm -f -- {} \;
```

Comment: `find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +365 -delete` would be easier.

Comment: -delete isn't in my aix find so I'm not accustomed to using it. I'm glad its implemented in other find binaries though.

Comment: `find … -exec rm -f {} +` will be a little faster (and it's portable except to ancient systems).

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to use `--` in case the first file name begins with a `-` (although you can guarantee it won't happen if the directory passed to `find` doesn't begin with a `-`).

Comment: This is extremely dangerous as you don't see what you are about to delete and why in the world are you force deleting with -f? Some files are protected for a reason. It's much more safe to store the results of find into a file, then examine them and run rm on contents of the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are removing lots of files this is typically a lot faster than "-exec" or piping to "xargs":

```
find . -type f -mtime +365 | perl -lne unlink
```